# How to replace multiple patterns with given array?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have string like

```
$text = "Hello :name its your :num_visit";
```

and Array

```
 $attr = [ ":name" => "Danny", ":num_visit" => 6];
```

I want to replace $text's patterns like :name, :num_visit with given values in array (Array have same key names).

Is it possible with php?

Comment: Have you tried something or did some research ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) and pass the search/replacement array as second argument, .e.g

```
<?php

    $text = "Hello :name its your :num_visit";
    $attr = [":name" => "Danny", ":num_visit" => 6];
    echo strtr($text, $attr);

?>
```

output:

```
Hello Danny its your 6
```

Comment: Its easier and better then other solution. Thank You

Comment: @user3720709: the main advantage is that `strtr` parses the string only once for all key/value pairs when `str_replace` parses the string for each key/value pair.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_replace()` to replace those. Pass the `key`s for `search` and `value`s for `replace` -

```
$text = "Hello :name its your :num_visit";
$attr = [ ":name" => "Danny", ":num_visit" => 6];

echo str_replace(array_keys($attr), $attr, $text);
```

**OUTPUT**

> Hello Danny its your 6

[str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace)

[Working code](https://eval.in/353851)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_replace()`.

```
$text = "Hello :name its your :num_visit";
str_replace( array(':name',':num_visit'), array('Danny','6'), $text );
```

`:name` will replace with `Danny` and `:num_visit` will replace with `6`.